# Почему в TextView выводятся цифры (по 4шт) при русской раскладке?

Tags: java, android

Почему при включенной русской раскладке клавиатуры выводятся наборы цифр, а не буквы? Как это исправить?

Comment: Это может быть баг девайса, прошивки, приложения-клавиатуры. ПОпробуйте запустить на эмуляторе/другом девайсе

Comment: Ну или код покажите.То, что вы описываете - вряд ли кто-то когда-то встречал

Comment: По 4 говоришь? Вроде коды символов представляют собой по 4 цифры. Видимо вы выводите не символ а его код, я клавы не писал, но все же скиньте код, постараюсь помочь

Comment: Да код собственно стандартный. В Layout прописал <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            /> и все. Компилирую, набираю на клавиатуре слова, а на экране, на каждую букву выползают 4 цифры. А если английская раскладка, то все Ок.

Comment: Пробовал в другом эмуляторе, то же самое.